How to prevent karate from encoding special characters?
Hi I am having a karate test .In my test I have some request parameters. These parameters have special character such as semicolon.
The following is my test
Feature: Executor for Test Cases with no request body
  Background:
    * configure ssl = false
    * configure charset = null
  Scenario Outline:
    * def destinationUrl = 'http://localhost:' + destinationPort
    * def reqHeaders = read(reqHeadersFile)
    * def requestPath = reqPath
#    * def requestPath = reqPath+'?'+reqParams
    * configure httpVersion = <httpVersion>
    #####################
    # Setup and send the request
    #####################
    Given url destinationUrl
    Given path requestPath
    And param zzz = '123;456'
    And param aaa = '123'
    Given headers reqHeaders
    When method reqMethod

In my test there is a param named zzz and it value is '123;456'  , when i execute my test i could see the semicolon is replaced with  %3B . The following is the output from wireshark .
GET /echo1?zzz=123%3B456&aaa=123 HTTP/1.1
sba-router-destination-service-name: localService
sba-router-destination-service-namespace: local
User-Agent: Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.0-beta2 (Java/1.8.0_362)
Host: localhost:9876
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json
echo-server-header: Openet
3gpp-Sbi-Message-Priority: 24
content-length: 478

{"serverHostname":"localService","reqeustMethod":"GET","requestHeaders":{"x-http2-scheme":["http"],"host":["172.22.0.2:8090"],"user-agent":["Vert.x-WebClient/4.4.4","Apache-HttpAsyncClient/5.0-beta2 (Java/1.8.0_362)"],"x-request-id":["2682e648-4002-747b-ad4b-d738c9bc536d"],"x-http2-stream-id":["3"],"x-http2-stream-weight":["16"],"content-length":["0"]},"requestUri":"/echo1?zzz=123%3B456&aaa=123","requestParams":{"zzz":["123;456"],"aaa":["123"]},"requestBody":"BODY NOT SET"}

In the wireshark you could that karate test driver is replacing semicolon with %3B any idea how can i prevent it from encoding it ?
thank you
